# Perl which line belongs to which category

Tags: perl

I have following output:

```
dis vlan 100
VLAN ID: 100
VLAN Type: static
Route Interface: configured
IP Address: x.x.x.
Subnet Mask: y.y.y.y
Description: Text
Name: SomeMoreText
Tagged   Ports:
Bridge-Aggregation1      Bridge-Aggregation2      Bridge-Aggregation3
Bridge-Aggregation6
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/21
Untagged Ports:
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/1
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
```

and I'm trying to map which ports are know to the vlan and in what kind of way (tagged or untagged). I'm having some problems with determing if a port is tagged or untagged. The code:

```
foreach my $specificVlanLine (split "\n",$getSpecificVlanValue){
    chomp $specificVlanLine ;
    if ( $specificVlanLine =~ m/dis vlan/ ){
        #do nothing
    } else {
        if ( index($specificVlanLine, ":" ) != -1) {
            my @specificVlanSplit = split(":", $specificVlanLine) ;
            $specificVlanSplit[0] =~ s/\s+//g;
            $data{$vlanID}{$specificVlanSplit[0]} = $specificVlanSplit[1] ;
        } elsif ( $specificVlanLine =~ m/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/ ) {
            $specificVlanLine =~ s/\s+//g;
            $data{$vlanID}{"TaggedPorts"} .= "$specificVlanLine \n" ;
    }
}
```

`$getSpecificVlanValue` is the complete output with which I started this question.

The problem is that every interface is put in taggedPorts. Which makes sense but how can I determine which Ethernet port is Tagged and which is Untagged?

```
TaggedPorts' => 'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18
  Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20
  Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/21
  Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/18
  Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
```

Expected output:

```
TaggedPorts' => 'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18
  Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20
  Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/21
  Ten-GigabitEthernet2/0/18
UntaggedPorts' => 'Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Guru Added the expected output to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a "flag" variable that remembers the port type ($mode in the example below):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $vlan_id = 'id';
my %data;

my $mode;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (/Tagged   Ports:/) {
        $mode = 'tagged';
    } elsif (/Untagged Ports:/) {
        $mode = 'untagged';
    } elsif (my ($key, $value) = /(.*):(.*)/) {
        $data{$vlan_id}{$key} = $value;
    } elsif (m{\d/\d+/\d} && $mode) {
        push @{ $data{$vlan_id}{$mode} }, $_;
    }
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%data;

__DATA__
dis vlan 100
VLAN ID: 100
VLAN Type: static
Route Interface: configured
IP Address: x.x.x.
Subnet Mask: y.y.y.y
Description: Text
Name: SomeMoreText
Tagged   Ports:
Bridge-Aggregation1      Bridge-Aggregation2      Bridge-Aggregation3
Bridge-Aggregation6
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/21
Untagged Ports:
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/1
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
```

Comment: Mmmh, my dumper is empty now but could be that I did something wrong. Will check further

Comment: Can't seem to get it working this way @choroba. Could you try your code with mine? So not through a while <DATA> but with my foreach

Comment: Just replace `while (<DATA>)` by `for (split /\n/, $getSpecificVlanValue)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
$\="\n";

sub getEmptyIfNull{
    my $val = shift;
    if (not defined $val){
        return "";
    }else{
        return $val . "\n";
    }
}


my %data;
my ($tagged,$untagged)=("","");
while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    if (/^Tagged/){
        $tagged="Y";
        $untagged="N";
    }elsif (/^Untagged/){
        $untagged="Y";
        $tagged="N";
    }

    if (/\d+\/\d+\/\d+/){
        if ($tagged eq "Y"){
            $data{"Tagged"} = getEmptyIfNull($data{"Tagged"}) . $_;
        }elsif ($untagged eq "Y"){
            $data{"Untagged"} = getEmptyIfNull($data{"Untagged"}) . $_;
        }
    }
}
    print Dumper \%data;


__DATA__
dis vlan 100
VLAN ID: 100
VLAN Type: static
Route Interface: configured
IP Address: x.x.x.
Subnet Mask: y.y.y.y
Description: Text
Name: SomeMoreText
Tagged   Ports:
Bridge-Aggregation1      Bridge-Aggregation2      Bridge-Aggregation3
Bridge-Aggregation6
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/18
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/20
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/21
Untagged Ports:
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/1
Ten-GigabitEthernet1/0/2
```

Comment: Could you explain the subfunction?